# mySQL "DESCRIBE" table returning long string of hyphens

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm using a Ubuntu Linux Virtual Machine to learn how to use mySQL. But one day I tried to use the DESCRIBE table command in the Terminal, and it returned to me a very very VERY long string of hyphens. It also takes at least a good 2 minutes on average for the command to finish processing, saying it only took 0.25sec to do it. I'm guessing it is the actual table itself, and that the display is messing up. I'm still very new and have very little knowledge of the mySQL commands and I might have typed in something to mess up the display settings.

Using "show tables" also does not show a nice clean table, but a table that's too long it so it folds.

What is happening and how do I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Try appending `\G` on your command, instead of `;`. That gives you row-oriented output, instead of column-oriented.

Comment: Your table is likely huge, and you're getting a tabular output. Try `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` instead of `DESCRIBE tablename` to get the SQL output instead.